# 'No match for call' when initializing objects after declaration

Tags: c++, oop

Following code gives me

```
test2.cc:248:14: error: no match for call to '(Integrator) (Input, double)'
test2.cc:249:11: error: no match for call to '(Integrator) (Integrator&, double)'
```

on compilation.

```
class Integrator : public Block {
    private:
            ... 
        Input input;    
        double init_value;              
    public:
        Integrator();
        Integrator(Input i, double initval = 0) : input(i), init_value(initval) {}
        Integrator(Integrator &i, double initval = 0) : input(i), init_value(initval) {}
...
};

// + is overloaded
Input operator + (Input a, Input b) { return new Add(a,b); }

int main() {
    Constant a(4.0); // Input
    Integrator x,y;
    ...
    x(y + a, 0.0); // + is overloaded for Inputs
    y(x, -2.0);
    ...
}
```

I'm posting only pieces of code as this is my homework. I can add more if these are not enough. I saw similar code working so I tried to use it (with some edits) but it doesn't work for me...

Comment: Thank you all guys. I'm new to OOP in C++ and I'm a little bit confused, so I forget basic principles sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

You can't initialize objects after they're declared. `x()` tries to call `x` as a function.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do would only work on initialization. 
Or You need to create a member function taking such arguments.

```
Integrator x; 
x(1.2) // Calling the constructor doesn't make sense here
```

You can only call the constructor directly on initialization (as already said).

```
Integrator x(1.2) ;
```

A member function sounds like the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

You can not "initialize" objects using the constructor after they have been defined. What you can do is override the `operator()` function for the syntax you want:

```
class Integrator : public Block {
    ...

public:
    void operator()(Input i, double initval = 0)
        {
            input = i;
            init_value = initval;
        }

    ...
};
```

Comment: While it's techincally possible to do that, it would be a very counter-intuitive use of `operator()`, leading to a maintenance headache. I would strongly suggest using a named member function instead.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg I tried your example (I'll change to member function later) and error changed to  undefined reference to `'Integrator::Integrator()'` with http://pastebin.com/JvFZLQ2n